# Automatic creation of a functional expression given initial conditions in python

Tags: python, function

I am currently working on a project involving various polyhedra, and due to that, each have
unique topology and connection of vertices and edges. Given the fixed vertices of 1 triangular face of a polyhedra, you can write a corresponding function `F` which relies on the initial conditions of the polyhedra in question (that being the list containing all unknown vertices, and a list of all the edges and faces of the polyhedra).

For example, one of the polyhedra is an octahedron, whose corresponding `F` function is given by

```
def F(r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z):
   return ((r**2 + s**2 + t**2 - 1) ** 2 + ((1 - r) ** 2 + s**2 + t**2 - 1) ** 2 + ((1 - u) ** 2 + v**2 + w**2 - 1) ** 2 + ((0.5 - u) ** 2 + (math.sqrt(3)/2 - v) ** 2 + w**2 - 1) ** 2 + ((0.5 - x) ** 2 + (math.sqrt(3)/2 - y) ** 2 + z ** 2 - 1) ** 2 + (x**2 + y**2 + z**2 - 1) ** 2 + ((r - u) ** 2 + (s - v) ** 2 + (t - w) ** 2 - 1) ** 2 + ((u - x) ** 2 + (v - y) ** 2 + (t - z) ** 2 - 1) ** 2 + ((r - x) ** 2 + (s - y) ** 2 + (t - z) ** 2 - 1) ** 2)
```

The result of the function itself is not the issue in question, but rather, given a different polyhedra, or better, any polyhedra whose initial conditions are different, is there a way to make python create this function for me? What tools are needed for this to happen?

I thought about creating some type of function that takes the list of the vertices, edges and faces of the solid and uses that to create the `F` function, like `def F(lst_vert, lst_edges, lst_faces):` but have no idea how to make python create something that involves variables, as in the future, partial derivatives of every variable are applied to `F` so it is vital for `F` to be a mathematical function with many variables.

The way I am doing things currently is working out the `F` function for each solid, which is very tedious (seeing as there are 92 total polyhedra), and quite mathematically demanding, especially since it is not a machine doing this for me. The partial derivative works perfectly, but that is, when the F function is already given by me. I don't know how that will change if this function is implemented the way I am envisioning.

Is what I am asking for even possible? Or will I probably have to write all of these functions by hand?

Comment: You can simply put the function inside of another function, this is called a closure

Comment: Have you used [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)? You should be able to compute symbolic partial derivatives and make new functions without crafting each situation by hand.

Comment: I am using sympy for the partial derivatives, but was not aware of the creation of other functions, I will look into that.

Comment: So there's 2 different meanings of the word "function" here. A mathematical function `f(x) = x^2`'s right-hand-side can be represented by the Python expression `x**2` where `x` might be a `sympy` variable. The idea is to be able to craft a Python function which returns Python expressions representing mathematical functions. For example, it should be trivial to write a Python function `def integrate_polynomial(sympy_expression, n): ...` which integrates an expression `n` times - that's making a new *mathematical function*.